# Dropzone.js : Screen hangs when uploading large number of files

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Using Dropzone.js  (http://www.dropzonejs.com/),I am trying drag and drop of around a 1000 files, my browser window freezes and results in high memory and CPU usage( 2 CPU show ~90% usage in my i7 core processor). Is there any fix/workaround/suggestion for this issue?

I am asking this because products like Google drive don't show these symptoms, so I am assuming there might be a fix/workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will work on this, and it will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks. Also, it would be nice if you can share your thoughts with me as to how you are going to implement it. Maybe I can spare some time and give it a try myself.

Comment: Hi @enyo, canyou please tell whether the issue has been fixed?
Trying to add to dropzone 1300 files. It freezes for some time and then displays all the files at once.